# iOS6 CALayer freeing/unloading for views in a scrollview that are scrolled non-visible

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, calayer

I'm aware that under iOS6, a UIView's CALayer is automatically unloaded and freed in low memory conditions, instead of the views themselves being unloaded. I love this new feature, so much easier to deal with.

However, just one corner-case i'd love clarification on: If i have a UIScrollView with a lot of child views, under low memory conditions, are the views that are scrolled out of the visible area eligible for layer unloading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume so, yes.

And it's the bitmap of the CALayer that's actually cleaned up.  Check out this [blog](http://thejoeconwayblog.wordpress.com/2012/10/04/view-controller-lifecycle-in-ios-6/).

Comment: Voting you as correct for linking to that awesome blog entry!